# What different options are there to start bitcoin on command line?

Tags: bitcoind

I had troubles with my client on a Raspberry because it was using the wrong configuration file and I could not find any entry in the configuration file that referred to the right location of the data directory, but I knew it was beeing used correctly in the past.

I was trying to use `-printtoconsole` to debug the problem but that did also not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On command line bitcoin can be started in several ways

`bitcoind` starts a process with the current user. This way the home directory of this user will be searched for a config file and will be used as data directory as default.

`service bitcoin start` will use the startup script `/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service`. This might contain a link to a configuration file. In my case this config file did not contain of a data directory which I found troubling. But the solution is that it contains a **user**. This user's home directory is then automatically referred to.

So, in my case I was using the terminal as user `pi` and had to start the process as user `bitcoin` instead. This can be done by

```
sudo runuser -l bitcoin -c 'bitcoind'
```